# Get first screen column in vim

Tags: vim

Is there any way to get the first visible (virtual) column in a window?
For example if I have wrap off, and scroll horizontally 3 times, the first visible virtual column would be 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use movement `g0`.
See `:help g0`.

Answer (score 1):

Someone from the mailing list suggested

```
 1 + virtcol(".") - wincol()
```

which also works, and makes me feel stupid.

Comment: This is a good first approximation, but it ignores some factors that could easily make it incorrect, e.g. the value of the `foldcolumn` option.